# How to open UDP port 7 or 9 for WOL on ubuntu?

Tags: networking, wake-on-lan, ubuntu-14.04

I have made all the necessary changes required for wakeonlan on my Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. Yet it does not seem to work. Also http://www.canyouseeme.org/ is showing that my UDP ports 7 or 9 are not open. I want to know how to open these ports.

Comment: You need to set port forwarding on your router for ports 7 & 9 to your Ubuntu internal IP. Test WOL on your LAN first. Use an app on your phone, for example. Check your computer BIOS settings as there should also be an option to enable WOL.

Comment: I have done port forwarding on my router and also enable WOL in BIOS.

Comment: Does it work inside your LAN? When you shutdown Ubuntu does it do it gracefully? We find that any shutdown problems and a machine won't WOL.

Comment: Just found this: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WakeOnLan

Comment: Nah it does not work on LAN. Yes my Ubuntu shuts down without any hiccups. But can you give me what kind of shutdown problems that I should expect.

Comment: The end of the page might help - editing `interfaces` file to add the WOL option automatically when your PC next boots. If the computer, say, loses power and (upon power restore) then WOL won't work because the NIC hasn't been prepared to wait for a Magic Packet.

Comment: My /etc/network/interfaces has following contents: 
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
Is this causing error?

Comment: No, it's just that your Ubuntu is using its Network Manager to configure your NIC so it doesn't have to use the "interfaces" file. You can still edit the interfaces file add: `auto eth0 iface eth0 inet dhcp up ethtool -s eth0 wol g` - where eth0 is your first ethernet adapter. Don't forget to reserve your Ubuntu IP in your router so it always gets the same IP.